# getting page from twitter or facebook anonymously by curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, twitter, anonymous

I'm trying to make some kind of page parser (more specific - highlighting some words on pages) and i've got some problems with it. I'm getting whole page data from url using curl and most pages are cooperating nicely, while others don't.

My goal is to get all page html just like browser is getting it and I'm trying to use it anonymously - like browser is. I mean - if some page needs log in to show data for browser that doesn't interest me. The problem is that I can't get on Twitter or Facebook pages that I can reach anonymously from regular browser, even when I set all headers just like they are send normally form Firefox or Chrome.

Is there any way to simply emulate browser to get page from these side or I have to use OAuth (and can someone explain why browsers don't need to use it)?

**EDIT**
I got the solution! If somebody will have problems with that you should:
-> try to switch protocol from https to http
-> get rid of the /#!/ element if there is one in url
-> for my curl element "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" was also causing problems.. dunno why, but now everything is OK

code of mine:

```
if (substr($this->url,0,5) == 'https')
        $this->url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $this->url);

    $this->url = str_replace('/#!/', '/', $this->url);

    //check, if a valid url is provided
    if(!filter_var($this->url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return false;

    $curl = curl_init();

    $header = array();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    // -> gives an error: $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($response) return $response;

    return false;
```

All was in class, but you can extract code very easy. For me it's getting both (twitter and facebook) nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution! If somebody will have problems with that you should:
-> try to switch protocol from https to http
-> get rid of the /#!/ element if there is one in url
-> for my curl element "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" was also causing problems.. dunno why, but now everything is OK

code of mine:

```
if (substr($this->url,0,5) == 'https')
        $this->url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $this->url);

    $this->url = str_replace('/#!/', '/', $this->url);

    //check, if a valid url is provided
    if(!filter_var($this->url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
        return false;

    $curl = curl_init();

    $header = array();
    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    // -> gives an error: $header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: pl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank. 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; pl; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if ($response) return $response;

    return false;
```

All was in class, but you can extract code very easy. For me it's getting both (twitter and facebook) nicely.

Comment: Also if there is "/home.php#!/' you should get rid of that part, couse it will force you to the login page..
so 3rd line should be replaced for something like this:  
`$this->url = str_replace('/home.php#!/', '/', $this->url);
$this->url = str_replace('/#!/', '/', $this->url);`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible to emulate a browser: but you need to carefully watch all the http headers (including cookies) that are sent by the browser, and also handle redirects as well. Some of this can be "automated" by cUrl functions, the rest you'll need to manually handle.

Note: I'm not talking about HTML headers in code; these are HTTP headers sent and received by browsers.

The easiest way to spot these is to user [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to monitor the traffic. Choose a URL and look on the right for "inspect element" and you'll see headers that get send, and headers that are received.

Facebook makes this more complicated with a mirad of iFrames, so I suggest you start on a simpler website!

Comment: Thank you, but I already send HTTP headers to get HTML page =)
All was figured out (first post), but thanks for the program - very useful.

Comment: Good stuff: you should post as an answer (not just as an edit); you can answer your own question so it's clearer for others as I'm sure there will be others that attempt the same!.